# Как перебрать массив и оставить только необходимые значения?

Tags: python, массивы, json, циклы, zabbix

Появилась задача сделать такую штуку на питоне:
Через библиотеку `py-zabbix` обращаюсь к API Zabbix'а.

В ответ получаю такой массив данных -

```
[
  {
    "itemid": "30171",
    "clock": "1535500848",
    "value": "21.6000",
    "ns": "117344023"
  },
  {
    "itemid": "30171",
    "clock": "1535500907",
    "value": "21.7000",
    "ns": "209859168"
  },
  {
    "itemid": "30171",
    "clock": "1535500967",
    "value": "21.7000",
    "ns": "229296223"
  }
]
```

Что требуется:
Выдать из всего этого только значения ключа `value`. Что-то типа такого -

```
21.7000,
21.6000,
21.7000 и т.д.
```

Далее из этих значений получить минимальное, среднее и максимальное. Макс., ср. и мин. - отдельные переменные.
Как это реализовать?

P.S. API не предоставляет возможность выдать только ключ `value` и его значения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [52]: vals = [float(x['value']) for x in data]

In [53]: vals
Out[53]: [21.6, 21.7, 21.7]
```

минимум:

```
In [54]: min(vals)
Out[54]: 21.6
```

максимум:

```
In [55]: max(vals)
Out[55]: 21.7
```

среднее:

```
In [56]: sum(vals)/len(vals)
Out[56]: 21.666666666666668
```

PS `In [XXX]:` и `Out [XXX]:` - это prompt в IPython (интерактивный Python) - их вводить не надо.

Comment: Выдает ошибку name 'In' is not defined

Comment: `In [XXX]:` и `Out [XXX]:` - это prompt в IPython (интерактивный Python) - их водить не надо

Comment: Работает! Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [map()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map)

```
arr = [
  {
    "itemid": "30171",
    "clock": "1535500848",
    "value": "21.6000",
    "ns": "117344023"
  },
  {
    "itemid": "30171",
    "clock": "1535500907",
    "value": "21.7000",
    "ns": "209859168"
  },
  {
    "itemid": "30171",
    "clock": "1535500967",
    "value": "21.7000",
    "ns": "229296223"
  }
]

result = list(map(lambda v: v["value"], arr))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы рекомендовал

```
vals = [float(x.get('value')) for x in data]
```

На случай, если где-то каким-то образом не будет записи с ключом "value". Код из ответа выше полностью рабочий, но мы ведь не можем доверять всем на слово.